# imputation based on values of a column

Tags: python, pandas, imputation

need to do imputation on similar dataframe, but imagine big data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data) df

    |name   |job        |age|weight |meal_price |date
|---|-------|-----------|---|-------|-----------|--------
|0  |Alex   |teacher    |27 |160    |8          |6-12-2022
|1  |Ben    |doctor     |32 |209    |11         |6-12-2022
|2  |Marry  |engineer   |78 |130    |27         |6-12-2022
|3  |Alex   |teacher    |27 |164    |19         |6-13-2022
|4  |Ben    |doctor     |32 |206    |7          |6-13-2022
|5  |Marry  |engineer   |78 |132    |10         |6-13-2022
|6  |Alex   |teacher    |NaN|NaN    |NaN        |6-14-2022
|7  |Ben    |doctor     |NaN|NaN    |NaN        |6-14-2022
|8  |Marry  |engineer   |NaN|NaN    |NaN        |6-14-2022
```

is there a way to do the imputation based on values in column 'name'? meaning for the imputation, the model only works at data for 'Alex',...
What makes it difficult is that my database has about a million unique names, which makes using sth similar to for loops not feasible.
thanks in advance

Comment: Which database are you using? If performance is an issue, it might be better not to use pandas but a database driver if there is one and use SQL to do the imputation.

Comment: I get the data from Azure data explorer, and I was using pandas, but you are right it is very slow and needs high computations.

Comment: In which form do you get the data from Azure? Is there a pandas method for directly fetching it, or do you have it in a local file, or in a Python object like list etc. before putting it into a pandas dataframe?

Comment: I saved the file as csv and loaded it on juputer notebood using pd.read_csv

Answer (score 1):

Is this too slow?

```
new_df = df[df.name == "Alex"]
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, since I have about 1,000,000 names, I was using for loop going through each name like you suggested, but it's very slow. I was just wondering if there is any faster option you could think of. thanks

Comment: Maybe look at using something like Dask.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used it myself yet, but PyArrow sounds very much like it could be suitable for your requirements. Since the data is present as CSV file, you should be able to load it easily: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/csv.html